# Simple ASP.NET 4.5 async and await in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to get a simple example of async with await working but I don't think it is.  I am thinking this code should take 10 seconds (or just over 10 seconds) to run as each function within the for each loop is supposed to run asynchronously.

This is an asp.net web forms and Async="true" is present in the page declaration.

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'This needs to execute different asynchronous processes based on the array value
    Dim ItemList(2) As String

    ItemList(0) = "A"
    ItemList(1) = "B"
    ItemList(2) = "C"

    Dim time_start As DateTime
    Dim time_end As DateTime

    Dim r1 As String
    Dim r2 As String
    Dim r3 As String

    'capture start time
    time_start = DateTime.Now

    'run async processes for each item in array
    For Each element As String In ItemList
        Select Case element
            Case "A"
                r1 = Await processAsyncA(10) & "  "
            Case "B"
                r2 = Await processAsyncB(10) & "  "
            Case "C"
                r3 = Await processAsyncC(10) & "  "
        End Select
    Next

    'capture end time
    time_end = DateTime.Now

    'display total duration in seconds
    Label1.Text = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, time_start, time_end)

End Sub

Protected Async Function processAsyncA(ByVal waittime As Integer) As Task(Of String)
    Await Task.Delay(waittime * 1000)
    Return waittime.ToString
End Function

Protected Async Function processAsyncB(ByVal waittime As Integer) As Task(Of String)
    Await Task.Delay(waittime * 1000)
    Return waittime.ToString
End Function

Protected Async Function processAsyncC(ByVal waittime As Integer) As Task(Of String)
    Await Task.Delay(waittime * 1000)
    Return waittime.ToString
End Function
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am having a problem with VB.NET and the Task.delay;  I have pretty much duplicated the code from above.  But when I run the code, the browser just locks up.  Almost as if the Thread continues to run and never releases itself back to the calling thread(UI).   Notice: Thread.sleep does work, but it keeps my code run synchronously.  I am looking for running in Parallel.  Any help of Task.Dely does lock up my Proof of concept(in the above example) would be much appreciated. I even tried using the [ANSWER] below; and the browser just stops working (locks-up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they won't run asynchronously because you've said "don't carry on until you've got the result" here:

```
r1 = Await processAsyncA(10)
```

What you should instead do is launch all of the `processXXX` functions and *then* await all of them. Something like:

```
Dim l as New List(Of Task(Of String))

'run async processes for each item in array
For Each element As String In ItemList
    Select Case element
        Case "A"
            l.Add(processAsyncA(10))
        Case "B"
            l.Add(processAsyncB(10))
        Case "C"
            l.Add(processAsyncC(10))
    End Select
Next

r1 = Await l(0) & "  "
r2 = Await l(1) & "  "
r3 = Await l(2) & "  "
```

(Not the cleanest code, but hopefully you get the gist)

Comment: +1. You can also use `Task.WhenAll` to await multiple tasks at once.

Comment: Thanks!  Your logic makes sense but I think there is still an issue with the syntax: when I replace my For Each block with the code you provided I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error at this line:

Add(processAsyncA(10))

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: I'm not sure Task.WhenAll would help since I don't think my functions are running asynchronously in the first place.  Please provide a code example if I am missing something......

Comment: @sqlchris - oops. Missing a `New` when declaring `l`. Quick fix,

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed that I missed that one but you're right, that did the trick.  Thank you!!!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - in production, the functions that I am trying to run asynchronously include web service calls and executing SQL stored procedures.  Is it possible that one (or all) of these things could be causing everything to run synchronously?  I tried adapting your code to our production system and am still seeing things run synchronously.  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @sqlchris - there may be other things happening that force (some) serialization to occur. As a simplest example, if async function you're calling was to issue a lock against the same object, then they'll obviously serialize. Sometimes, the actual lock isn't so obvious, e.g. if you're making multiple web requests, you can hit limits on the number of parallel requests that the client will issue to the same server, or (if they're "sessionful") the server may only service one request at a time.